# Save toggleClass state of dynamically generated divs and store with Cookie/LocalStorage

Tags: javascript, jquery, cookies

I am trying to save my toggleClass state of multiple dynamically generated divs and store them with LocalStorage, so they're available either on page refresh or re-visiting the page. I stuck in the middle of my code and have no more ideas.
Any solutions i found here, will not work, either they refer to a single element or they use a mix of addClass/removeClass and save state.

Saving with Cookie would be an option too.

**Html:**

```
<div id="row_parent_41" class="parent">
<div id="page_41">
<span class="showhide" id="more_2"><img src="plus.png" /></span>
</div>

<div id="holder_41" class="child">stuff goes here</div>
```

**jQuery:**

```
var inactiveHolder = localStorage.getItem('child') == 'true';   
$(".showhide").on('click', function() {     
$(this).closest(".parent").find(".child").slideToggle().toggleClass('inactiveHolder'); 
$('.child').toggleClass('clicked', inactiveHolder );
return false;
});
```

Comment: Store it with localStorage if it don't have to be sent to the server in every request you do

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Does this code work for you?

```
var inactiveHolder = localStorage.getItem('child');   

// set initial state
if (inactiveHolder == 'true') {
    $('.child').addClass('clicked');
}

// change localstorage and class
$('.showhide').on('click', function() {
    var element = $(this).closest(".parent").find(".child");
    $(element).slideToggle().toggleClass('clicked'); 
    localstorage.setItem('child', $(element).hasClass('clicked'));
    return false;
});
```

Comment: Thanks Jasper, but it does not work (there is a typo in your code which i changed also (.hasClass('clicled'));)).. but no luck. Strange, but lots of other solutions out there do not work either. I even made tests by minifying the html to a minimal in case there was a conflict between the nested "childs" within childs

Comment: I looked at your fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/1nhmx821/4/ It works for me, i added a console.log and alert. Class is applied when clicked, and is applied when in localStorage.

Comment: Indeed.. you are right...and Thank You. But the state of the "child" divs (opened/closed) is always open (where class 'clicked' should keep the 'child' div closed aka 'display:none'